# Converting a Mercurial repository to Bazaar

Tags: mercurial, bazaar

Is there an easy way of converting an existing Mercurial repository to Bazaar without losing any history? If I convert Mercurial to Subversion to Bazaar will I lose any history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [bzr-fastimport](https://launchpad.net/bzr-fastimport) plugin. It has hg-fastexport helper to dump your Mercurial history to fastimport stream which can be imported into Bazaar branch.

The entire history should be preserved this way. There is one type of information which will be lost though: information on file copies, because bzr does not support that.

Another option is to use [bzr-hg](https://launchpad.net/bzr-hg) plugin which should be able to work directly with Mercurial repositories. Because you're asking for an easy way then I suggest to try bzr-hg first.

Answer (score 1):

According to the help for hg convert ("hg help convert"), it only converts to type of Mercurial or SVN (Bazaar is only supported as a source repository).  If you decide to go Mercurial -> SVN -> Bazaar using "hg convert", the help file says history on branches isn't preserved.